# How to check if a child window exists?

Tags: delphi

I have a main form (MainForm) and a MDI child window (TFormChild).
I want to create multiple TFormChild forms, but the first one must behave in a certain way so I need to detect if a TFormChild window already exists.

I use this code but it is not working:

```
function FindChildWindowByClass(CONST aParent: HWnd; CONST aClass: string): THandle;   
begin
  Result:= FindWindowEx(aParent, 0, PChar(aClass), NIL);
end;
```

I call it like this:

```
Found:= FindChildWindowByClass(MainForm.Handle, 'TFormChild')> 0;
```

Comment: Why are you testing `>0`? Surely the correct logic is `<>0`. Not that that is your problem, just an aside.

Comment: @David, as of Delphi 4, with the introduction of a 32-bit unsigned integer type, handles in Delphi are unsigned, so it technically makes no difference.

Comment: @Rob I know it makes no difference to the behaviour, but logically it's very different. `>0` implies that the ordering is important. `<>0` indicates that `0` is a sentinel value.

Comment: David is right. But this is only a minor issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call it like

```
Found:= FindChildWindowByClass(MainForm.ClientHandle, 'TFormChild')> 0;
```

MDI child windows are children of the ['MDICLIENT'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#creating_frame), [`ClientHandle`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TForm_ClientHandle.html) property of TCustomFrom holds the handle.

Comment: I accepted your answer because it answers my question specifically. However, I want to give credit also to Hasan since I will use his more-Delphi-like solution.

Comment: @Altar - You asked a clear question which both this and Hasan's answer provides a solution. You may accept whichever suits more. I'm fine with the vote you've casted on this answer. :)

Answer (score 14):

In a form, you can refer to the MDIChildCount and MDIChildren properties.

for example :

```
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i:= 0 to MainForm.MDIChildCount-1 do
  begin
    if MainForm.MDIChildren[i] is TFormChild  then
    ...
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: +1; but isn't enough to check `if MainForm.MDIChildCount > 0 then` if OP wants to wait for the first form creation ?

Comment: @daemon_x there may be MDI children of a different class

Comment: @David - I got the sentence `I want to create multiple TFormChild forms, but the first one must behave in a certain way so I need to detect if a TFormChild window already exists` as OP is creating only TFormChild windows and he wants to check if the first one has been created, but who knows..

Comment: I have indeed other forms (classes). Plus, you never know how the program will evolve in the future. Even if I don't have other classes NOW, maybe I will add later...

Comment: Thanks a lot Hasan! I will use your solution.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to accomplish this is to have the form you want to open actually check to see if it already exists.  To do so your, form must declare a class procedure.  Declared as a class procedure, the proc can be called regardless of whether the form exists or not.

Add to your form's public section

```
class procedure OpenCheck;
```

then the procedure looks like this

```
Class procedure TForm1.OpenCheck;
var
f: TForm1;
N: Integer;
begin
   F := Nil;
   With Application.MainForm do
   begin
      For N := 0 to MDIChildCount - 1 do
      begin
         If MDIChildren[N] is TForm1 then
            F := MDIChildren[N] as TForm1;
      end;
   end;
   if F = Nil then //we know the form doesn't exist
      //open the form as the 1st instance/add a new constructor to open as 1st
   else
      //open form as subsequent instance/add new constructor to open as subsqt instance
end;
```

Add Form1's unit to your mdiframe's uses clause.

To open the form, call your class procedure, which in turn will call the form's constructor.

```
TForm1.OpenCheck;
```

One word of warning using class procedures, do not access any of the components/properties of the form.  Since the form does not actually have to be instantiated, accessing them would produce an access violation/that is until you know F is not nil.  Then you can use F. to access form components/properties.